# Injective Holomorphic Functions that are not Conformal?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible for a holomorphic function on a connected domain to be conformal but not injective? Also, is it possible for a holomorphic function to be injective but not conformal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Example.** The exponential function is conformal but not injective: its derivative is nowhere vanishing (so conformal) but $\exp 0 = \exp 2 \pi i$ (so not injective).

**Proposition.** The derivative of an injective holomorphic function $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$, where $D$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{C}$, is nowhere vanishing. In particular, $f$ is conformal.

*Proof.* We prove the a stronger statement, which will imply the contrapositive of the above proposition. Let $z_0 \in D$. By a change of coordinates if necessary, we may assume that $f(z_0) = 0$ and $z_0 = 0$ without loss of generality. Then, there is a positive integer $n$ and a holomorphic function $h : D \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = z^n h(z)$ for all $z$ in $D$ and $h(0) \ne 0$. So in particular there is an open neighbourhood $U$ such that $0 \in U \subseteq D$ and $h$ is nowhere vanishing on $U$. That implies that there is a holomorphic function $g : U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z)^n = h(z)$ for all $z$ in $U$. (Take a holomorphic branch of the map $w \mapsto w^{1/n}$.) So $f(z) = (z \, g(z))^n$ for all $z$ in $U$.

Note that $z \mapsto z \, g(z)$ has non-zero derivative at $0$ (since $g(0) \ne 0$), so by the inverse function theorem, if $U$ is small enough, $z \mapsto z \, g(z)$ is an *invertible* holomorphic function on $U$. This implies $f$ is an $n$-to-$1$ function on $U \setminus \{ 0 \}$. But if $f'(0) = 0$, by considering the power series of $f$, we must have $n \ge 2$.

We conclude that a holomorphic function $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ has derivative vanishing at $z_0$ if and only if it fails to be locally injective at $z_0$.

(This is probably my favourite result in complex analysis.)

Comment: I happen to stumble across this now. Is there a simple way to determine if a given conformal map is injective (aside from trying to find or not find two points, etc)? Perhaps a clever use of the inverse function theorem or something?

Comment: @mixedmath: There is no a priori reason to expect anything nice to happen. The inverse function theorem is a result about *local* behaviour, and conformality is a local property, while injectivity is a *global* property.

Comment: 10 years later, but, perhaps you could still help me understand this part of your proof: "$z\mapsto zg(z)$ is an _invertible_ holomorphic function in $U$. This implies $f$ is an $n$-to-$1$ function on $U\setminus\{0\}$". How can we be sure that all $n$ roots of a certain value from $f(U\setminus\{0\})$ are in the image of $U$ through $z\mapsto zg(z)$? Or perhaps I misunderstood this part.

Comment: Write $k (z) = z g (z)$. We have $f (z) = k (z)^n$, and $k$ is invertible, so the solutions of $w = f (z)$ are given by $k^{-1} (v)$ where $v$ are the $n$ different $n$-th roots of $w$.

Comment: Yes, but how do we know for sure that all the $n$ roots $v$ are in the domain on $k^{-1}$, that is in $k(U)$?

Comment: We are assuming $f (0) = 0$ and $w$ is a small non-zero complex number. We already know $k$ is invertible on $U$, so by shrinking $U$ further if necessary, we may assume $k (U)$ is a small disc centred on $0$. This ensures that $w \in f (U)$ has the property that all of its $n$-roots are all in $k (U)$.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. It's a little different than you said, though. Since $U$ is open and $k=(k^{-1})^{-1}$, then $k(U)$ is the inverse image of an open set through a continuous function, hence open. It contains $0$, so there is a ball $B$ around $0$ in $k(U)$. Then $f$ is not injective on $k^{-1}(B)$.

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible for a holomorphic function to be injective but not conformal; for a holomorphic f to be injective, its derivative must be non-zero, and conformality of f is precisely equivalent to having $f'(z)\neq 0$.

On the other hand, it is possible for f to be conformal but not injective: $expz:=e^z$ is one example.Conformality follows from the fact that f(z) is analytic , and $\frac{de^z}{dz}=e^z$, and $e^z\neq 0$;
(use the identity $e^ze^{-z}=1$ to show $e^z\neq 0$)

EDIT:  Conformality follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations , which show that the effect of f'(z) is that of stretching and rotating. If f'(z) is not zero, then any  tangent vector forming an angle $\theta$ will be rotated, under f'(z) by an agle $\theta$, so that two vectors $v,w$ forming an angle $\gamma$ between them, will each be rotated by the same amount, with the effect that the net difference in the angles of the vectors v,w, and their respective images f(v),f(w) is $\theta -\theta=0$

Comment: Yes! I forgot that there was such a easy example! Thank you!

Comment: @Braindead: A simpler example of a conformal but not injective function is $z \mapsto z^2$ in a domain that does not include the origin.

Comment: @lhf: but my point in using $e^z$ was that its "non-injectivity" is extreme, in that it is $\infty\rightarrow 1$

Comment: This is strange; my answer had been accepted, and somehow it was unaccepted. I had never seen this before.

Comment: @gary - After I accepted your answer, Zhen Lin posted another answer, which I accepted because it completely answered my question by reminding me that all holomorphic functions look like $z\to z^n$ locally. I mean, it feels like you are taking this personally for some reason judging from a series of edits you've made, but I didn't mean any offense. I definitely upvoted your reponse.

Comment: @Braindead: sorry, I kind of lost it for a while, my bad.

Comment: @Braindead: my apologies, actually; I displayed a lack of class there; my reaction had nothing to see with you. Sorry.

Comment: @gary - No need for apologies.